# Length of getElementsByClassName() array changes when removing class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to improve my vanilla JavaScript and was trying to write a function that removes the class "active" from a list item and a corresponding `div`.  My code is as follows:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
console.log(elems.length);

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
  elems[i].classList.remove("active");
  console.log("end", elems.length);
}
```

When I first log `elems.length` I get 2.  After the first time through the loop `elems.length` is now 1.  This obviously causes a problem in the functionality of the code.

Why is using `classList.remove` causing the length of `elems` to change?  How can I get the proper functionality without using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a live collection; it will change as fewer (or more) elements match it.

The easiest way around this is to do your removals in reverse:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("active");

for (var i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  elems[i].classList.remove("active");
}
```